# Sort by partial key name in json column

Tags: postgresql, json

I have column `document` of data type `json` with logging data like:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(document)
AS
  VALUES (
    '{
      "blocks": {
        "participant-information_primary__Primary__39011__2288960": {
            "first_name": "First name"
        }
      }
     }'::jsonb
  ), (
    '{
      "blocks": {
        "participant-information_primary__Primary__39011__2288969": {
            "first_name": "Joe ZZZ"
        }
      }
     }'
  ), (
    '{
      "blocks": {
        "participant-information_primary__Primary__39011__2288169": {
            "first_name": "AAA ZZZ"
        }
      }
     }'
  ), (
    '{
      "blocks": {
        "participant-information_primary__Primary__39011__1288169": {
            "first_name": "kkk"
        }
      }
     }'
  );
```

Key name *'participant-information_primary__Primary__39011__2288960'* is dynamic and can vary by the trailing integer number. I want to do something like:

```
ORDER BY document->'blocks'->'participant-information_primary*'->>'first_name'
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I'd store the integer part separately.  Then you may be able to have a slightly different JSON structure that can be searched to your liking.

Comment: Yes, but I need to save here id. But I found an answer on my question. Will post it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [**`json_object_keys()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) like you found yourself already (or `jsonb_object_keys()` for `jsonb`), you can do this with simple inline SQL. I suggest a `LATERAL` subquery.

If, like your example suggests, there is ***exactly one key*** inside the key  'blocks', the solutions is simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl, json_object_keys(document->'blocks') AS part
ORDER  BY document->'blocks'->part->>'first_name';
```

The comma is short notation for `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`.

If there can be ***any number of keys***, you need to be more verbose:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT part
   FROM   json_object_keys(document->'blocks') part
   WHERE  part ~ '^participant-information_primary__Primary__'  -- your pattern here
   LIMIT  1  --  just to be safe
   ) s ON true
ORDER  BY document->'blocks'->part->>'first_name';
```

The `LEFT JOIN` preserves rows where no matching key is found at all.

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Comment: Great, we have one more solution

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem

```
    -- field should be escaped already
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_sort_by(_j json, field text) RETURNS text AS $$
        declare key    text;
        declare search text[];
    BEGIN
        search := string_to_array(field, '.');
        IF field ~ '^blocks' THEN
          FOREACH key IN ARRAY ARRAY(select json_object_keys(_j->'blocks')) LOOP
            IF key ~ ('^'::text || search[2]) THEN
              return _j->'blocks'->key->>search[3];
            END IF;
          END LOOP;
          return '';
        ELSE
          return json_extract_path_text(_j, VARIADIC search);
        END IF;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

And then in SQL query run order by json_sort_by(json, 'fddf.fdfd.fdfd')